# Missing charset header error

Tags: html, meta-tags

I have tried the following code. But still Charset header is missing, error is coming

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
```

I have used this line as well:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">...
```

but the error persists.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />` ,Try with small `c` in content Type.

Comment: Tried.Still error persist.

Comment: A meta tag is _not_ an http header. Those are separate things.

Comment: paste some more html along with exact error

Comment: I am trying this out in site analyzer for seo.It gives error like Charset header is missing.
Header : (Missing) 
Meta : utf-8

Comment: is that site you analyzing build on `php`?

Comment: There is some confusion about representations and their domains: The http headers - among them 'content-type' - are part of the data stream sent from the server to the client (browser). The html is part of that data stream, notably the payload. The charset spec in a meta tag is part of the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing / at the end of the meta tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start your HTML-document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it's not in META of page (I spent a few hours on this way), it's in server configuration, adding charset configuration in ngingx virtual server configuration

> charset UTF-8;

I don't know about apache configuration but it should be very similar
try somethin like :

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8

now I have a problem, while I type 
curl -I www.w3sos.com (my testing environment)
I don't see the result, but when I use a web test solution like site analyzer it works ...

good luck, it was my 50 cents for this questions

greg